# Format the last cell only with value equal or higher than X

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

How do I use conditional formatting to format only the last cell in each column with a minimum value ?
This implies a non-VBA solution.

I have tried using this formula, but it stops after first match (5 is formatted):

```
AND(A2>=5,COUNTIF($A$2:A2,">=5")=1)
```

Using this data, only 9 should be formatted.

**Data**:

```
1
2
3
4
5  <-- actual result
6
7
8
9  <-- expected result
```

**UPDATE:**
This formula seems to do the trick, but only works when the cell values in the range are numeric, which mine are, and **only** in 1 column. Range must match format area.
Note: I found the "INDEX..E+307" part somewhere else, but lost the URL so cant give credit.

```
AND(A2>=5,A2=INDEX($A$2:A10,MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,$A$2:A10)))
```

A multi-column supported formula is now needed. Using `OFFSET` might be the way to go..

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading the problem as this:

We want to highlight the last cell in the column, but only when the cells in that column contain at least one sufficiently large value.

Assuming data starts in `A1`, I came up with this:

```
=AND(COUNTIF(OFFSET(A$1,,,COUNT(A:A),1),">=5")>0,ROW()=COUNT(A:A))
```

There are some assumptions there: like we can say that the number of non-empty values can be counted by `COUNTA()`, or that data starts in row 1 so that we can find the last row with `ROW()=COUNT(A:A)`. But hopefully you get the idea...

If you are in fact looking for the greatest value, not the last one, then this be a starting point:

```
AND(A2>=5,A2=MAX($A$2:A10))
```

That should work to locate the highest value across multiple columns as well. If your table can grow over time then you should look at defining the range with an `OFFSET()` formula.

Comment: Unfortunately your formula assumes cell value 8 is on row 8, which is a problem. See my update for a formula without this limitation.

Comment: So you wanted to highlight the maximum (or highest or greatest) value? "Last" typically implies the end by position. No problem.